# How can I connect multiple lights to a switch downstream?

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I am installing multiple lamp holders for my garden bed to use par 38 flood light bulbs. I purchased all weatherproof materials that is rated for outdoors ( dug trench, purchased uf 12/3)

The power source is coming from the garage right to the lights, then after the last light will be the switch inside the bar. What would be the correct way to connect all of these lights to the one switch? Also want to put an outlet and another light inside bar. I’ve attached a diagram for better understanding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBpg0.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Is this bar inside an outbuilding, or a freestanding outdoor thing?

Comment: Freestanding outdoor

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to run your 12/3 from the panel to the switch location. In the panel hook your black wire to your circuit breaker, the white wire to neutral and ground to ground. You can cap the red wire and leave a note to what you're doing. At each light location connect your fixture white to your white feed and your other fixture wire, probably black, to the red feed wire. In the switch box, pigtail the feed black to the switch and to your outlet. Pigtail the white to the outlet and to the extra light. Pigtail the red to the switch and to the extra light.

Comment: How much would this change if I wanted to do a three way circuit ? Basically two switches: after the power source and before the first light and after the last light

Comment: In a nutshell, you'd need to run an additional UF cable for the travelers for the 3-way switches, which isn't allowed. You would have to run conduit the whole way and pull individual conductors.

Comment: So in laymen’s terms, basically I have to daisy chain each light?